# Need help to find a value to linearize the data

Tags: mathematical-optimization, scripting

I have a two column data which is y vs x. I want to linearize the data by this formula 1/(x-b) but I don't know how to determine the b value such that the ln(y) vs 1/(x-b) becomes a linear line. So I script the following code to plot the ln(y) vs 1/(x-b) with changing the b value manually and by looking at the ln(y) vs 1/(x-b) graph to find the best linear behavior. Do you know a better way of doing it instead of changing the b value manually?

```
x = {331,334,335,336};
y = {10,50,100,1000};
b = 290;
Xinv = 1/(x - b)
lnY = N[Log[y]];
(data = Transpose[{Xinv, lnY}]) // MatrixForm;
ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> {"O"}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Darker@Green, PointSize[3]}]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a*x + b, {a, b}, x];
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotMarkers -> "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"O\",\nFontWeight->\"Plain\"]\)"], Plot[nlm[x], {x, -1, 2}],
  Frame -> True]
```

Comment: I think the problem is that `x` and `b` are used as arguments to `NonlinearModelFit`. Try `NonlinearModelFit[data, a*s + t, {a, t}, s]`

Comment: Dear Rohit Namjoshi, the goal is to find the best value of "b" to obtain the best linear line for the lnY vs Xinv data

Answer (score 1):

You assign values to `a` and `x` and ***also*** use the same names in 2nd, 3rd, and 4th arguments of `NonlinearModelFit`. You shouldn't do that because they get evaluated before `NonlinearModelFit` sees them. You need to use different names.

```
x = {331, 334, 335, 336};
y = {10, 50, 100, 1000};
b = 290;
Xinv = 1/(x - b);
lnY = N[Log[y]];
data = Transpose[{Xinv, lnY}]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a u + bb, {a, bb}, u]
```

[image: fit]

```
Show[
  ListPlot[data],
  Plot[nlm[x], {x, -1, 2}], 
  Frame -> True]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

OK, I think I finally understand what you want. Based on that improved understanding, I suggest you try using `` to find the value of `b` that gives the best fit to your data. Like so:

```
Block[{invX, data, nlm},
  With[{xx = {331, 334, 335, 336}, lnY = N[Log[{10, 50, 100, 1000}]]},
    invX[b_] = 1/(xx - b);
    data[b_] = N[Transpose[{invX[b], lnY}]];
    nlm[b_?NumericQ] := NonlinearModelFit[data[b], a x + b, {a}, x]];
    Module[{bestB, pts, line, xmin, xmax},
      bestB = NArgMax[nlm[b]["AdjustedRSquared"], b];
      pts = data[bestB];
      line = nlm[bestB];
      xmin = pts[[1, 1]];
      xmax = pts[[-1, 1]];
      Show[
        ListPlot[pts,
          PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]},
          PlotLabel -> Row[{"b = ", bestB."\n"}]],
        Plot[line[x], {x, xmin, xmax}],
        Frame -> True]]]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: The code works but my main question is to find the "b" value to give me the best linear behavior of lnY vs. Xinv. Here I picked b = 290 which gives almost a linear behavior but there can be many b values but I don't know how to implement in Mathematica to obtain the best linear line of lnY vs. Xinv.

Comment: @Nini. Take a look at the update I made. Does it do what you want?

Comment: Hi @m_goldberg, the code is nice but if you try "b = 325" it gives you the lowest Standard Errors rather than "b = 152.241". Would it be possible to improve the code?

Comment: @Nini. The fit residuals for `b = 154.24` are `{0.396262, -0.536585, -0.672113, 0.810915}`. For `b = 325`, they are `{106.662, -34.8486, -62.7794, -83.8964}`. I don't see how `b = 325` produces a better fit. Even if I use the standardized residuals in place of the fit residuals I get a better score for `b = 154.24`. Perhaps there is a error in your calculations.